# See Sun source code on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I see Sun/Oracle code, in Java, on Eclipse? For instance, the source code of System.out.println.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you installed the JDK, did you opt to install the source as well? It's typically in src.zip. If you configure Eclipse to build against the JDK and specify the location of src.zip (if it's not detected automatically) you can just go into the JRE types like any other.

(Note that you can't easily see the exact code for `System.out.println` as it depends on the value of `System.out` at the time... but you can look at `PrintWriter` etc.)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that with eclipse. How would you go about configuring eclipse to build against the JDK with the source?

Comment: Btw how do we get the source code of classes like `sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets` ?

Answer (score 3):

Tell Eclipse to use the JDK as the Java runtime inside Eclipse.

Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's -> Add, and then point to the JDK installation directory.  Then check it to be the default used.

Answer (score 1):

To attach the JDK sources to a JRE that Eclipse is using:

Go to Window, Preferences, Java, Installed JREs, click on the JRE that you're using, click the Edit button. Then select the file `rt.jar` (the Java runtime library) and click the Source Attachment button. Enter the location of the `src.zip` file which should be in your JDK installation directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can't see the Sun/Oracle source code from eclipse directly. If it was your own code you would be able to right click on the method, say `println()`, and click "Open Declaration", and eclipse would show you the place where the method was declared. However, Eclipse doesn't package that source code with it, so it won't work with Sun/Oracle code.